# Defining "class" constructor and setting properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects, dom-events

I'm doing a JS script which will render a tree view with picking abilities.

But something strange is happening and i found out what it was, however this doesn't make me happy and i want to discover why it's happening.

```js
var picker1 = {},
  picker2 = {};
(function($) {
  $.fn.treePicker = function(params) {
    var exists = $(this).length > 0;

    if (exists) {
      params.controlDiv = $(this);
      var picker = new treePicker(params);
      return picker;
    }
  };

  var treePicker = function(params) {
    this.mapping.id = params.mapping.id; // Change to this.mapping = params.mapping;
  };

  $.extend(treePicker.prototype, {
    mapping: {
      id: 'id',
      text: 'text',
    },
  });

  var picker1 = $("#render1").treePicker({
    mapping: {
      id: 'Id1',
      text: 'text1'
    }
  });

  var picker2 = $("#render2").treePicker({
    mapping: {
      id: 'Id2',
      text: 'text2'
    }
  });

  $("#result1").val(picker1.mapping.id + "," + picker1.mapping.text);
  $("#result2").val(picker2.mapping.id + "," + picker2.mapping.text);
}(jQuery));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="result1" />
<input type="text" id="result2" />

<div id="render1"></div>

<div id="render2"></div>
```

I've two divs where the controls will be rendered.
To this demo I've two inputs where i show the pickers data.

I'm setting the property `picker1.mapping.id` and `picker1.mapping.text` `(line 24-29)` to match `id1` and `text1`.

```
var picker1 = $("#render1").treePicker({ 
    mapping: {
    id: 'Id1',
    text: 'text1'
  }
});
```

Then, I'm setting the same properties to `picker2` `(line 31-36)`.

My "constructor" is located on

```
var treePicker = function (params) {
  this.mapping.id = params.mapping.id; // Change to this.mapping.id = params.mapping.id
};
```

And I'm extending the "class" doing this:

```
$.extend(treePicker.prototype, {
    mapping: {
        id: 'id',
        text: 'text',
    },
});
```

The problem is that while doing this, `picker1.mapping.id` will not keep his own value and instead will hold `picker2` value.

But... if I change

```
this.mapping.id = params.mapping.id;
```

to

```
this.mapping = params.mapping;
```

It will work.
Any ideas?

Comment: objects are shared on assignment, primitives are copied once on assignment.

Comment: So it's not about how I'm constructing my main object/prototype but how i'm passing the mapping values, right?

Comment: i think so. you should generally only put functions on the `prototype` for that reason.

Comment: Hummmm, that's a good reason. It's my first plugin... Ok, and even if i don't put my properties on `prototype` they will be reachable from the prototype functions. Right?

Comment: prototype methods use `this.something` to reach properties of the instance they are attached to.

Comment: Roger that, and where should i put the properties that define my object? Could you formulate an answer so i accept it?